# query expand with Breezejs

Tags: breeze

i am sending a query with expand to the server

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Incidents")
                        .expand("IncidentComments")
                        .where("IncidentID", "eq", incidentId);
```

and in the http i an getting results which are ok, the entity with the related entity
how ever i cannot see the data when i return from the query in breeze
the IncidentComments has no comments

```
function getSucceeded(data) {
        $scope.incident = data;
        $scope.incidentComments = data.IncidentComments;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "IncidentComments" is a property of "Incident", then the comments will be returned as such.  So:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Incidents")
                    .expand("IncidentComments")
                    .where("IncidentID", "eq", incidentId);
var myEntityManager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
   var incidents = data.results;
   var incident = incidents[0]; // because you are only returning one incident;
   var incidentComments = incident.incidentComments; 
});
```

Comment: i am already doing it, my feeling is that it is in the edm, but i dont know what, i am using the webapi-odata as server side